# Adax implementation via Github repository

Tags: python

I'm new to Python and I'm trying hard to get the hang of it so bear with me here.

Recently I bought an Adax heater that is controllable via WIFI. The heater comes with an app that works just fine but I want to incorporate it into my Loxone domotics system.

I've been scrolling the net, reading up on the API provided by Adax but I couldn't get it the work.
[AdaxAPI](https://adax.no/en/wi-fi/api-development/)

So I moved on to searching the net and I found a repo on Github that's seems to cover the job aswel.
[GitHubLink](https://github.com/Danielhiversen/pyAdax/blob/main/adax/__init__.py)

However I'm lost on how to actually get it to work.

I've been able to reproduce the example provided on the page but what I would like to do is to change the temperature of a given room. I've been looking into the code and came up with the following:

---

Self-compiled, runs without error in PyCharm but has no effect on the temperature.

```
import asyncio
import datetime
import json
import logging
from aiohttp import ClientError
import async_timeout


ACCOUNTID = "****"  # get your account ID (6 digits) from the Account page in the Adax WiFi app
PASSWORD = "*****" # create a service password under "Remote Api" in the app

async def main():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        heater= Adax(ACCOUNTID, PASSWORD, session)
        for test3 in await heater.set_room_target_temperature(544514, 28,1):
            for test3 in await heater._write_set_room_target_temperature(
        print(test3),
       
asyncio.run(main())
```

Someone wants to lend a hand to help me fix this? The goal is to being able to adjust the temperature via Python script.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: No one could lend a hand here?